# push to git from vba on windows

Tags: git, vba, excel, ms-word

I am developing word and excel macros, however to keep revision control and track changes I would like to use GitLab

So what I have done so far is to have a code which export out all vba code to a folder on my PC(Z:/Dokumentstyring/GIT), when I run my publish sub routine:

```
Private Sub publish()
    ThisDocument.save

    Call ExportVisualBasicCode
    ' Here I would like to automatically push the code to GIT
    Call CloseAll
End Sub
```

Then I manually go into git shell and type:

```
git config --global user.name "xxxxx"
git config --global user.email "xxxx@xxxx.com"

cd Z:/Dokumentstyring/GIT
git init
git remote add origin xxxxxx/xxx/Dokumentstyring.git
git add .
git commit -m "Version Number - Date and a short comment"
git push -u origin master
```

Is there a way that I can get my publish routine todo this manually work for me?

Comment: I cannot get your question. You know that once you setup a repository you don't need to run the code every time, from the above code that you mentioned in the question you need to only run the 3 last lines. If you explain more what you want I might be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

It took some time, but I finally manage to solve this issue: The stripped down code looks like this:

```
Private Sub publish()

Dim hFile As Long
Dim FileContents1 As String
Dim versionNumber As String
Dim strFile1 As String
Dim revTekst As String
Dim gitFileCommands As String


revTekst = "Pusher no filene i koden til Github automatisk!!" '& "<BR>" _


versionNumber = Left(wordMakroVersjon, 2) & "." & Right(wordMakroVersjon, Len(wordMakroVersjon) - 2)


Call ExportVisualBasicCode

Call pushToGit(versionNumber, replace(revTekst, "<BR>", vbNewLine))
gitFileCommands = replace(Settings.CMRDISK & "Dokumentstyring\gitCommands.sh", "\", "/")
Shell "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\sh.exe --login -i -c """ & gitFileCommands & """"

End Sub


Public Sub pushToGit(versionNumber As String, releaseNotes As String)

Dim FileContents1 As String
Dim strFile1 As String

strFile1 = Settings.CMRDISK & "Dokumentstyring\gitCommands.sh"

On Error Resume Next
Kill strFile1
On Error GoTo 0

FileContents1 = "#! /bin/bash" & vbNewLine _
    & "cd Z:/Dokumentstyring/GIT" & vbNewLine _
    & "git add ." & vbNewLine _
    & "git commit -m """ & versionNumber & " - " & Format(Now(), "dd.mm.yyyy") & " " & releaseNotes & """" & vbNewLine _
    & "git push -u origin master" & vbNewLine _
    & "read -p ""Press enter to continue"" "


Open strFile1 For Binary As #1
Put #1, , FileContents1
Close #1

End Sub
```