# Execute Git Bash from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, git, git-bash

I need help how to execute Git-bash command from Excel VBA
I want to split my csv into multiple file
I am using code I got from here:[push to git from vba on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47695139/push-to-git-from-vba-on-windows) but dont work.

Here is my code.

```
Sub Split_JPN_Rolled()

Dim gitFileCommands As String
Dim Fname As Variant

    Dim CurrentDate As String

    For i = 1 To 4
    Select Case i
    Case 1
    CurrentDate = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
    Case 2
    CurrentDate = Format(Date - 1, "yyyymmdd")
    Case 3
    CurrentDate = Format(Date - 2, "yyyymmdd")
    Case 4
    CurrentDate = Format(Date - 3, "yyyymmdd")
    End Select

    Fname = "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\SPM Raw Data\JPN_6M_DMD_Rolled_" & CurrentDate & ".csv"
    If Dir(Fname) <> "" Then
    Shell "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\git-bash.exe --login -i --cd=""C:\Users\Name\Desktop\SPM Raw Data"" ""split JPN_6M_DMD_Rolled_*.csv JPNRolled -l 1048500 -a 2 -d"""

    Exit Sub
    End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Save the file with the .sh extension instead of the .csv extension and git bash should run the bash script file.