# Migration Subversion -> GitHub

Tags: github, svn, migration

our company will migrate from Subversion to GitHub this year. The department I'm working with uses SVN purely as 'file storage' - no real SCM. We deliver XML-Files to our customers (which are developed in other departments) and store the files in SVN purely for traceability. Every time we deliver XML-Files, a branch is created which contains the files. In trunc, we have a directory that contains all XML-files ever delivered and that directory is updated (checkout of trunc -> simple file copy of the XML-Files -> new commit) every time a branch was created. Furthermore, the creation of a branch and update of trunc are scripted (VBA)

So now my questions: how could we achieve the same goal with GitHub?

Thanks in advance,

Rainer

No experience with GitHub up to now, gathering information

Comment: Not really sure I understand. Maybe I can explain a little bit how branches work in git so you can decide for yourself if it works for you. In git, you have sequences of commits that describe, each one of them, the full contents of the project at that commit Each commit also identifies what is their _parent_ commit, that is so that you can know the history of the commit that you are dealing (a recursive sequence of following _the parents_). Finally, branches in git are just _pointers_ to commits.... they can be created, deleted, moved around at will... all git cares about are the commits.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you don't make any modification to the files stored, you don't need branch in Git.

Simply add and commit your XML files on each delivery, plus add a tag to the commit you just created ([`git tag -m "new delivery" vX.y.Z`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag), or any other tag name which helps you track each delivery).
You can execute a Git bash script from a VBA script, as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49007603/6309).

That will enable traceability (each delivery content can be compared/diffed against a past commit/delivery).

Comment: VonC and etshift0, many thanks for your answer, especially for the link to the VBA/bash script.